# Objective-C ARC Minor Performance

Tags: objective-c, memory, automatic-ref-counting

I was just curious as to whether or not ARC compilation optimizes memory performance in examples like:

```
1| - (void)setName:(NSString *)name
2| {
3|    _name = name;
4|   if([name isEqualToString:@"Name"])
5|       NSLog(@"%@", @"It's Equal!");
6| }
```

versus a minor difference of not using the local `name` variable on line 4 a second time

```
1| - (void)setName:(NSString *)name
2| {
3|    _name = name;
4|   if([_name isEqualToString:@"Name"])
5|       NSLog(@"%@", @"It's Equal!");
6| }
```

Does ARC optimize memory performance by only keeping the local `name` variable in the memory for just the one assignment to `_name` in the second example and then releases it, or is `name` kept in the memory regardless until the method is complete for both examples? Hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Have you looked at the generated assembly (or IR) output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only difference in your two sets of code is the variable used in the `if` statement. That little difference has absolutely no bearing on the assignment of `name` to `_name`. Memory management is no different between your two sets of code.

In both sets of code, the line `_name = name;` essentially becomes (under ARC):

```
if (_name != name) {
    [_name release];
    _name = [name retain];
}
```

Your `if` statement and the variable it uses is completely irrelevant to that code.

Remember, `name` is "owned" by whatever code calls the `setName:` method. The `setName:` method will never attempt to release `name`. The object pointed to be `name` will be kept in memory by whatever is keeping a reference to it.

Comment: thanks! that was very helpful! so it doesn't matter really which one I use in the if statement or any following statements for that matter?